# Huawei Matebook HZ-W19 Wirelesscard Driver BCM 4356

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom, firmware, huawei

I'm using Ubuntu on my Huawei Matebook HZ-W19.

My wireless card (BCM 4356) doesn't work with the latest version of linux-firmware (1.173.3) but works with version 1.156. Howerver, with this last one, my desktop glitches (Budgie, Gnome, Deepin, KDE).

So now I'm asking myself if it is possible to get the driver for the wireless card from 1.156 and to insert it into the 1.173 package.

Output from `lsmod; dmesg | egrep -i 'brcm|firm'`

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 77824  4
ipmi_devintf           20480  0
ipmi_msghandler        53248  1 ipmi_devintf
cmac                   16384  1
bnep                   20480  2
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
sch_fq_codel           20480  3
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             212992  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   106496  1
cdc_ether              16384  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
usbnet                 45056  1 cdc_ether
kvm                   598016  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
input_leds             16384  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
r8152                  61440  0
mii                    16384  2 usbnet,r8152
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             548864  33 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
ecdh_generic           24576  2 bluetooth
hid_multitouch         20480  0
snd_soc_skl            90112  0
snd_soc_skl_ipc        65536  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_ext_core       24576  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_dsp        32768  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_sst_ipc        16384  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_acpi           16384  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_core          241664  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
snd_hda_intel          40960  3
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920  7 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_skl
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                98304  8 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
spi_pxa2xx_platform    24576  0
pcbc                   16384  0
joydev                 24576  0
8250_dw                16384  0
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    16384  0
aesni_intel           188416  2
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
hid_sensor_accel_3d    16384  1
wacom                 106496  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
brcmfmac              315392  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
hid_sensor_gyro_3d     16384  0
hid_sensor_trigger     16384  6 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd                    81920  19 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
industrialio_triggered_buffer    16384  2 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
soundcore              16384  1 snd
hid_sensor_iio_common    16384  3 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_accel_3d
brcmutil               16384  1 brcmfmac
cfg80211              622592  1 brcmfmac
intel_cstate           20480  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
shpchp                 36864  0
wmi                    24576  1 intel_wmi_thunderbolt
mei_me                 40960  0
acpi_als               16384  0
int3403_thermal        16384  0
intel_vbtn             16384  0
kfifo_buf              16384  2 industrialio_triggered_buffer,acpi_als
idma64                 20480  2
industrialio           69632  7 industrialio_triggered_buffer,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_trigger,acpi_als,kfifo_buf,hid_sensor_accel_3d
virt_dma               16384  1 idma64
acpi_pad              180224  0
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
intel_lpss_pci         20480  0
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_pci
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
processor_thermal_device    16384  0
int3400_thermal        16384  0
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  2 int3403_thermal,processor_thermal_device
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
intel_soc_dts_iosf     16384  1 processor_thermal_device
intel_hid              16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  2 intel_hid,intel_vbtn
mac_hid                16384  0
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
uas                    24576  0
usb_storage            69632  3 uas
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  1 wacom
hid_sensor_custom      20480  0
hid_sensor_hub         20480  5 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_iio_common,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_custom
intel_ishtp_hid        20480  0
i915                 1617920  14
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        172032  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  0
intel_ish_ipc          20480  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
drm                   401408  5 drm_kms_helper,i915
intel_ishtp            40960  2 intel_ishtp_hid,intel_ish_ipc
i2c_hid                20480  0
hid                   118784  7 i2c_hid,wacom,usbhid,hid_multitouch,hid_sensor_hub,intel_ishtp_hid,hid_generic
video                  45056  1 i915
pinctrl_sunrisepoint    28672  1
```

Comment: Probably unwise - spend your effort on debugging your configuration of the current version. `apt changelog linux-firmware` is a starting place.

Comment: Isn't the driver for your device *bcmwl-kernel-source*? It is not a part of linux-firmware. It is provided by its own deb file. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I thought this as well but it seems to depend on some firmware from linux-firmware aswell

Comment: Got the wireless problem fixed with the help of this https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/8pvd34/found_solution_for_bcm_4356_adapter_problems_in/ But the glitches came back after connecting to my wireless network any idea for that?

Comment: @chili555 it might be the SDIO wifi card

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsmod; dmesg | egrep -i 'brcm|firm'`

Answer (score 0):

Okay the Solution for the Wirelessproblem was here: https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/8pvd34/found_solution_for_bcm_4356_adapter_problems_in/

And the Screen Flickering was solved by adding this Kernel Parameter:

```
i915.edp_vswing=2
```

Thanks for Comments very nice Community here.